# Grep check PHP files starting or ending with EOL

Tags: php, grep, eof, eol

So, I just spend an hour looking through A LOT of php files for en EOL after a closing ?>. I tried regex matching it to make it easier, but with a big project `\?>(\n){1,}$` still ended up getting me 450+ results. That, and the problem turned out to be an EOL BEFORE the opening `<?php` ...

So, I guess there *HAS* to be a better way. I was thinking GREP looking for files starting or ending with an EOL.

So what is the best way to solve these issues?

Comment: What issue? What error? Is it `OUTPUT ALREADY STARTED?`  If so, the error normally shows what file and what line caused the output.

Comment: An EOL after an ?> or before an <?php will cause them to appear before all output (above the <doctype> even. This causes issues when generating image, csv or xml output, for example. No error given.

Comment: You can match the `EOL` with `$`...so you can for example: `grep '<?php$' *` or `grep '$?>' *`

Comment: @Berry M right, so perhaps you have output buffering enabled?, because without that, you would be getting errors that point out what file caused the output and yes, it may be at the beginning or end of the file, but knowing the filename to review is the biggest hurdle. After that, the fix is trivial.

Comment: Hint, partial solution: you can use `grep -rn -B1 "<?php"`. this will print out all lines with "<?php" in them and the line just before. If it shows "--" as the line before, it means there is no line before, -- is the group separator. -r = recursive, -n = show linenumbers, -Bx = show also x lines Before. For closing tag it becomes `grep -rn -A1 "?>"`. Here -Ax = show lines After.

Comment: Thanks @Zimmi, I can figure out a simple script with that most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a regex in Eclipse and searching all .php files.

I ran `/(^<?\s{1,}<\?php|\?>\s{1,}$)/g` and found out I had two EOL before an opening `<?php`.

This regex can also be used with grep.